# Retrofit returns null error message with status 400

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I have created an app to use REST api developed by me. Android client is written with [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library.

there I have created an interface as ObjectIFaceAsync

```
public interface ObjectIFaceAsync {
@POST("/")
public void addArea(
        @Body Area area,
        Callback<JsonElement> data
);
}
```

then I implemented it in a button click

```
Area pojoArea = new Area();
pojoArea.setArea(area.getText().toString());
pojoArea.setDistrict(district.getText().toString());
pojoArea.setProvince(province.getText().toString());
pojoArea.setAreaType(areaType.getSelectedItem().toString());
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(URLs.ENDPOINT + "/restaddarea")
    .build();
ObjectIFaceAsync objectIFaceAsync = restAdapter.create(ObjectIFaceAsync.class);

try {
    objectIFaceAsync.addArea(
        pojoArea, new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonElement jsonElement,retrofit.client.Response response) {
                if (jsonElement.getAsJsonObject()
                    .get("status").getAsString().equals("s")) {
                     //show a message 
                } else {
                    //show another message
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                //show a failure message
                }
            }
            );
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I have used the same endpoint to and sent a get request that is not having a JSON @Body. It works fine. Here I always get an error. means it always runs the **failure** method. I got displayed the

```
retrofitError.getMessage();
```

and

```
retrofitError.getResponse().getStatuse();
```

They show ***null*** and ***400*** respectively.

Can someone tell what I have to do to get this corrected. or what I have done wrong here.

thanks.

Comment: .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
 .setLog(new AndroidLog("your_application")) it will help you debug the  output

Comment: @PramodYadav Have I done other thing correctly??
because i am not sure whether I have missed any step.

Comment: Print the stacktrace of the RetrofitError. Could be there is no throwable in the RetrofitError, but there is only status code returned from the endpoint.

Comment: have you tried using `"/restaddarea"` as the path value and removing it from the endpoint definition. Generally the endpoint defintion should just be the scheme and domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
retrofitError.getBody()
```

to get String or

```
retrofitError.getBodyAs(MyError.class)
```

if you want to map the error json to object